# open a link new tab not working in android, but working from chrome and firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

i have project in phonegap and jquery mobile, in my project i want to open a link in my android with android browser but it does not work, but when i open a link from my browser (firefox and chrome) on windows it works? what's the problem?

this my javascript :

```
function displayIstilah(data) {
    var istilah = data.item;
    console.log(istilah);
    $('#GambarPic').attr("src", '' + istilah.gambar);
    $('#fullName').text(istilah.istilah);
    $('#Keterangan').text(istilah.keterangan);
    if (istilah.vidio) {
        $('#actionList').append('<li><a href="' + istilah.vidio + '" target="_system" location="yes"><h3>Vidio</h3>' +
                '<p>' + istilah.vidio + '</p></a></li>');
    }

    $('#actionList').listview('refresh');

}
```

and html :

```
<body>

<div id="detailsPage" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Istilah Astronomi</h1>
    </div>

  <div data-role="content"> 

    <img id="GambarPic"/>
    <div id="istilahdetails">
       <h3 id="fullName"></h3>
       <p id="Keterangan"></p>
       <p id="vidio" target="_system" location="yes"></p>
    </div>

    <ul id="actionList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Which browser did you try with in the android device? The pre-installed one? Try with Chrome Android.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [inAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html#page-toc-source) plugin to open links in a browser from your phonegap app.